# Ionic plugin barcodescanner

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

When I try to build the application "`ionic build android`" see the `error` below. This error only happens when I install `phonegap-plugin-BarcodeScanner`.
Anyone know what can this be?

```
Error: error code 1 for command: /path/to/app/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug, -b, /path/to/app/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

Comment: Check out this link - https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/141 If you are using android studio , then an update should or adding Anrdoid support Repository should do if you use CLI Keep me posted

Comment: Unfortunately not yet solved this problem.

Comment: still the same error?

Comment: Yes, same error. something with gradle version?

Comment: I'm using Ionic Framework CLI and sublime text editor. Not android studio.

Comment: I think that the problem was solved. What I did was remove a line from myapp-barcodescanner.gradle file. This is the code removed: compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'.

Now, it is working normally.

Comment: glad it worked. Did that link helped?

Answer (score 0):

Mostly this error happens because the gradle version of your project and the gradle version of a plugin is missmatching.

What you can do is removing the platform and add it again.

Open the project and deny the question from AndroidStudio to upgrade to the newest gradle version.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem was solved.
What I did was remove a line from myapp-barcodescanner.gradle file.
This is the code removed:
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'.

Now, it is working normally.